# Error while starting Oracle Weblogic Local Server 11g

Tags: java, apache, weblogic

Hi I am facing this error while starting my local Oracle Weblogic Server -

`<Oct 2, 2014 5:07:17 PM PDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:373)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:127)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:94)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:723)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 2, 2014 5:07:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
<Oct 2, 2014 5:07:17 PM PDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down>
<Oct 2, 2014 5:07:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>`

Please help!

Comment: Well, did you look at the complete stack trace in the log file?  It looks like some error parsing/transforming some XML - maybe a bad config file?

Comment: Did you recently deploy an application or library, specifically one that would have a different version of Xerces, or another Xml api that would include it?

Comment: @REW Yes, I recently deployed my application and all the libraries and it is the same as the one I had before.

Comment: Is this a BasicDomain or one of the other template domains?